# Does git-messenger support showing a commit using Magit?

Tags: magit, hooks, git

In [this issue](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-git-messenger/issues/25) in `git-messenger`'s issue tracker it was suggested that it should optionally use `magit-commit-mode` to show commits in a separate buffer. And that issue was closed as resolved.

But it appears that `magit-commit-mode` does not exists now. Is there a way to use Magit here anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called `magit-revision-mode` now.

But just turning on the mode as suggested in the documentation of `git-messenger` won't work. It should be using`magit-show-commit` instead. And no, just adding that to the hook instead won't work; that function has to be called with the commit as first argument.

In other words you have to ask the maintainer of `git-messenger` to add explicit support for Magit.

**Update:** `git-messenger` now supports Magit, see https://github.com/syohex/emacs-git-messenger/issues/25.